# Name of Round road in Center of Amritsar, India?

Tags: cartography, india, streets

#### New Info

I just found out this area used to be a wall with 12 gates. Portions of the wall are still there. Still researching name of roads, or portions of the road, such as Bazaar Rd on South-West part

[image]

#### Original Question

I wish to paint an Illustrated Map of [Amritsar, India](https://www.tourmyindia.com/blog/best-places-to-visit-near-golden-temple/), and I am perplexed because I cannot find name of this round road surrounding the center of Amritsar, India

[image]

I found a map of Amristar from 1849, but for the life of me, I do not know what this round road is.

[image]

Surely, there must be an accurate map somewhere that explains this!!!

Comment: Can you find it on OpenStreetMap?

Comment: I believe this map has a name for the road.  http://geosfera.info/uploads/fotos/amritsar2.jpg  I just can not make out what it is... Bassar Rd maybe??

Comment: @PolyGeo I just tried and it only shows traffic directions, https://www.openstreetmap.org/way/22826664#map=16/31.6195/74.8756

Comment: @ed.hankins Bazaar Rd. But what about name for rest of the circle? Isn't it possible that a long road may have multiple names, depending on where it's located?

Comment: I would imagine that indeed the name would change but I have never been there so I couldnt be sure.  I am just searching through various maps to see if I can locate any other names for you.

Comment: It was not until I lived in England for a few years that I heard the term ring road - as far as I know we do not use it in Australia. We would be more likely to give it a route number and to have names on the various streets/roads that it passes along.

Comment: For sure,  and just so you know I have looked at like 30 maps of that city and I can not find a single one with the name of that street.  Like this map http://www.amritsarcity.org/amritsar-golden-temple/amritsar-city-map.jpg  seems to give every street but that one :/

Comment: @ed.hankins Oh my goodness!!! Wow!

Comment: http://www.goldentempleamritsar.org/how-to-reach-golden-temple-amritsar/how-to-reach-golden-temple-from-delhi-by-train.jpg  am I wrong but I think this map is also calling that road HWY 15 also???

Comment: @ed.hankins I am guessing HWY 15 runs on it, but I'm sure it was there before highways were in place ...

Comment: Yup,  you have yourself a good little puzzle here!

Comment: I clicked on several businesses that appear to be on that street. Addresses ranged from "nr. petrol pump, XX Gate" to "Main Rd." to Sultan Wind Rd (southeast) which Google has labeled a spoke road with that name. Some places just referred to the closest Gate. Was it originally a wall?

Comment: @mkennedy that was my thought too - it does seem to follow a path that looks defensive.

Comment: @mkennedy Yes, I believe this was once a wall and it had 12 gates. I'm going to try and find if someone from FB (who is from Amritsar) can help out. https://www.facebook.com/permalink.php?story_fbid=1558896704378928&id=1530250143910251

Comment: @mkennedy According to Wikipedia, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amritsar, `Amritsar's central walled city has narrow streets mostly developed in the 17th and 18th century. The city is a peculiar example of an introverted planning system with unique areas called Katras. The Katras are self-styled residential units that provided unique defence system during attacks on the city.` This is different from Amritsar District, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amritsar_district Still waiting on FB people (it's the crack of dawn in Amritsar right now!)

Comment: Do you mean roundabout ?

Answer (score 1):

ESRI's ArcGIS Online has "Chitra Taqueg Road" for the northern portion. ["Chitra Taqueg" does not produce many results on Google.](https://www.google.com/search?q=Chitra+Taqueg)

[image: "Chitra Taqueg"]

The eastern portion is labeled "NH 15", but I believe that designation is now deprecated.

If you do find the name, please consider adding it to OSM.

Answer (score 0):

At http://oasisdesigns.org/chriday.asp the road is labelled as "Circular Road" or "Circular outer road" / "Outer circular road". See:
[image]

You can find there a lot of interesting information, incl. e.g. gate names.